# Mopub Integration

Tags: php, notifications, mopub

I am creating RTB bidder in php ,I understood basic concepts of using  Mopub as SSP. I just want to know how the bidder will come to know whether its bid is selected or not. Are there any test environment for this and within how much time we will get notification for bid?

Answer (score 3):

At this time if you're interested in participating as a DSP in our Marketplace you would need to contact BD [at] mopub.com, and we'll gladly work with you from there.